# Pywin32 --> COM -->Powerpoint tutorial?

Tags: python, com, powerpoint

Does anyone know where I could find a good list of objects and methods (or a tutorial) for working with powerpoint 2010. I was able to locate this:

http://nbviewer.ipython.org/urls/raw.github.com/sanand0/ipython-notebooks/master/Office.ipynb

but was hoping to find something a little more in depth.

I've also the book "Python Programming on Win32" but this is not PPT specific.

Comment: I've been looking for this notebook for so long, never thought I would find it in a SO question. The notebook is from a PyCon India 2013 talk available here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aKCXj1DyEhM The speaker is now the CEO of Gramener

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The com32 module provides access to all the .com methods of PowerPoint so I would start with the [MSDN PowerPoint 2010 API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff604967%28office.14%29.aspx) - one important trick is to create the python interfaces to the object libraries:

> To do this in Python, run
>   Python/Lib/site-packages/win32com/client/makepy.py and pick “Microsoft
>   Office 12.0 Object Library” and “Microsoft PowerPoint 12.0 Object
>   Library”. (If you have a version of Office other than 12.0, pick your
>   version.) 
>   *Found [here](http://www.s-anand.net/blog/automating-powerpoint-with-python/)*

Then rename the resulting files something sensible.

Comment: Silly question: what are the two files called when they are originally created? Nothing seems to have been created in /client?

Comment: There is probably a long, horrible name, in the directory that you ran the command from - sorry I don't have a windows machine to hand at the moment to check.

Comment: found it, accept the file is not created in the current directory, it is created in "Python/Lib/site-packages/win32com/gen_py"

Comment: Nice to know where it gets put!  To be honest personally I would always use html, animated GIF or possibly libre office given a chance - then you are not reliant on the end user having a specific MS-Office suite.  (You can also work cross platform).

Comment: for me it ends up in a temp folder... I instead wrote a script that imports makepy, sets commandline args with `sys.argv = ['', "-o", r"D:\pathtomystuff\MSO.py", "Microsoft Office 15.0 Object Library"]` then just call makepy.main() and the resulting library is dumped in the MSO.py file.  I then do the same for PowerPoint, Excel, and Word to MSPPT, MSXL, and MSWORD files. Hope this helps!

Comment: What do I do if the is no “Microsoft PowerPoint 12.0 Object Library”, I only have an object library for Office, nothing for Excel, Powerpoint, word, etc. This is very frustrating.

Comment: @Melendowski: I would guess that you have a version of MS Office that does not expose these object libraries, _(maybe 365)_ - I would suggest typing `pip search powerpoint` and then look into using one of the libraries listed instead.

Comment: So for those that also have this problem. My suggestion is start an office application, like say powerpoint and press alt+f11. This will bring up the vba project window. Goto tools->references. A list will show up with all available references. In it you will find all your missing object libraries, as well as their paths. You can manually run the makepy using syntax found http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/generate-a-static-com-proxy.html  on this paths. I believe the issue has to do with extensions being different than .tbl .exe or .dll For example powerpoint for me is a .OLB